# UnitTesting static Class (Theoretical Question)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3, static-classes

I know when is ok to use a Static Class, but my simple question is:

If there's a big problem when we're Unit-Testing our code that has some Static Class?

Is better just using a regular instances class?

Thanxs (i know there's some questions that talk about this, but all are based in particular case I just want to have a general opinion about it)

Comment: This is exactly a reason to avoid static/singleton classes; it precludes some unit testing cases where you need to provide a mock implementation.

Comment: If you have dependencies in your static class that you need to mock for testing, are you absolutely certain that a static class is the appropriate implementation?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is take the existing static class use as a seam, and provide an alternative implementation in a different namespace. This means that you can get the code under test with as few changes as possible -- just namespace changes. Typically I've had to do this to get round C# filesystem ops -- File.Exists etc.

Say your method basically does this:

```
using System.IO;

public void SomeMethod()
{
    ...
    if(File.Exists(myFile))
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

then I'd replace that implementation of File with an alternative. The alterntive implementation should stub out any existing methods, and make calls to delegate implementations under the covers -- e.g.

```
namespace IO.Abstractions 
{     
    public static class File
    {         
        public static Func<string, string, string> ExistsImpl =
                                                      System.IO.File.Exists;

        public static string Exists(string path)
        {             
            return ExistsImpl (path);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I'd modify the original code so that it uses the new namespace:

```
using IO.Abstractions;

public void SomeMethod()
{
    ...
    if(File.Exists(myFile))
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Then, in your test, you can just provide an alternative implementation of the behaviour for File.Exists, something like:

```
[Test]
public void SomeTest()
{
    // arrange
    ...
    File.ExistsImpl = (path) => true; // to just default to true for every call
    ...

    // act
    someClass.SomeMethod();

    // then assert
    ...
}
```

I wrote a blog with some more details recently [here](http://timbar.blogspot.com/2011/09/injecting-behaviour-for-static-method.html).